# Who can see me online on Messenger.com?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

When I access the new Facebook chat interface at Messenger.com, will I visible to all of my contacts, I just to the ones I've chosen to be visible to on the main Facebook website?

The ["Messenger on Your Computer" help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/735006619902401) doesn't mention this.